# Turbo C hangs while executing a C bubble sort program

Tags: c, sorting

I have written a C program to do a bubble sort but on executing it the IDE hangs.
Why does this happen? The code is below:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    main()
    {
          int i[3],temp,n,x;
          printf("Enter 4 positive numbers");
          for(n=0;n<=3;n++)
          {
                scanf("%d",&i[n]);
          }
          recheck:
          for(x=0;x<=2;x++)
          {
                if(id[x]>i[x+])
                {
                temp=i[x];
                i[x]=i[x+1];
                i[x+1]=temp;
                }
          }
          if(i[0]>i[1]&&i[1]>i[2]&&i[2]>i[3])
          {
                for(n=0;n<=3;n++)
                {
                      printf("%d",i[n]);
                 }
          }
          else
          {
                 goto recheck;
           }
           getche();
}
```

Comment: Does Turbo C really still exist?

Comment: `int i[3]` has only 3 elements. i[2] is the last.

Comment: int i[3] has 3 elements and you're reading 4 from the user

Comment: @Banthar you should make this an answer

Comment: I wonder what `i[x+]` might do.  Erm, no, I don't.

Comment: sorry thats not i[x+] its i[x+1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 bugs in this code.

1) you are declaring the variable as `i[3]`.  so it will take only three values. from `i[0]` to `i[2]`. you are reading four values. so as the array is limited to three, it cant read four values. If you wish to read four values then change `i[3]` to `i[4]`.

2)    `if(id[x]>i[x+])`. This line has two bugs. here you are using `id[x]`. but there is no variable declared as `id[]`. It should be `i[x]`. The second is `i[x+]`. this is not a valid declaration. it should be `i[x++]`.

3)  You are sorting the values in ascending order and checking them in descending order. 
   so this result in a bug. change `if(i[0]>i[1]&&i[1]>i[2]&&i[2]>i[3])` 
   with `if(i[0]<i[1]&&i[1]<i[2]&&i[2]<i[3])` or change `if(id[x]>i[x+])` with `if(id[x]<i[x+])`

4  You are using `goto` statement in your code. but `goto` is not preffered as it is a false programming practice. goto forwards or reverts back the execution process with out any function call. This is against a structured programming approach. so dont prefer `goto` statement. 
you can solve it easily by using two `for()` loops.

Comment: sorry theres no id i mistyped it.its only i

Answer (score 6):

You should always copy-paste your code. The code you provided has some typos and won't even compile.

Ignoring the typos there are three major issues:

1. `int i[3]` has only 3 elements. `i[3]` is out of bounds and accessing it can cause unexpected results.
2. When swapping elements you are sorting in ascending order but when checking if the array is fully sorted, you use descending order.
3. You are using strict inequality to check if the array is sorted. This won't work if there are two equal elements.

Comment: thank you. I did not know that it should be 4 as i thought it started from 0,1,2,3 locations